# Javascript selected item value not pulling correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I'm doing a select box with a list of items(dynamically created from an XML created by a webservice), and I'm unable to pull the selected value correctly. Here is what is happening.

What I'm sending:

```
onchange="changeFunction(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)"
```

What I'm receiving:

```
function (a){if(f.isFunction(a))return this.each(function(b){var c=f(this);c.text(a.call(this,b,c.text()))});if(typeof a!=
```

I'm the only thing I'm using is some self built functions and jQuery.

Any help would be superb.

Edit: here is the change function. All it is intended to do is build a form populated with values for given selected item.

```
function changeFunction(selection) {
    console.log(selection);
    $('#right').empty();
    var addNewFields = 'these will be the fields';
    $('#right').append(addNewFields);
}
```

Here is the select in question:

```
<select class="userSelection" id="userSelection" size="10" style="width:150px;" onchange="changeFunction(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)"></select>
```

This is literally all the code in the html part of it. It's being populated via ajax, and there are 2 divs, one for left, containing the select, and one for right, containing the content for the user.

Just for giggles, here is the code creating the options:

```
        var optionTag = '<option value="' + $(this).find('optionID').text + '" >' + $(this).find('optionName').text() + '</option>';
            $('#userSelection').append(optionTag);
```

Comment: Where are you receiving this? How does the `changeFunction` look like? What does it do?

Comment: I'm using console.log within the changeFunction to see what is being sent to it. I'm updating with the changeFunction to show you what it's doing.

Comment: Great, also show a bit of your markup. For example the DOM element to which you are applying this onchange attribute.

Comment: Your code looks fine. Here's a live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ehURZ/1/. There must be something else going on. A part of your code that you haven't shown us. Try creating a jsfiddle example illustrating the problem you are encountering.

Comment: See, that's literally all that I'm doing, and it's not working on my page.

Comment: Did you check my jsfiddle example which illustrates that your code should work perfectly fine? Can you provide a jsfiddle example illustrating your issue?

Comment: I may have found it... It may be in the just for giggles... the $(this).find('optionID').text is being displayed as the erroneous string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var optionTag = '<option value="' + $(this).find('optionID').text + '" >' + $(this).find('optionName').text() + '</option>';
```

should be:

```
var optionTag = '<option value="' + $(this).find('optionID').text() + '" >' + $(this).find('optionName').text() + '</option>';
```

Notice that `$(this).find('optionID').text` should be `$(this).find('optionID').text()`.

or even better, to avoid this soup:

```
var optionTag = $('<option/>', {
    value: $(this).find('optionID').text(),
    html: $(this).find('optionName').text()    
});
```

Comment: goodness gracious thank you so much. I can't believe it was something so dumb. Oy vey.

Comment: @SpencerCole, glad I could help. Do you have some other questions or you might consider closing this thread?

Comment: The only thing I'm confused about is now it is showing the error "Uncaught TypeError: Property 'value' of object #<HTMLOptionElement> is not a function"

Comment: It's coming from an 'anonymous function'/onchange

Comment: @SpencerCole, sorry I have no idea. If you don't show your code I am completely clueless. Unfortunately I cannot read your mind. And if you decide to show your code, please don't just post some random bits. Post a full and consistent example.

Comment: I'm showing you all the code I have. I've changed things that are sensitive. 106 lines of code, 1-14 is php, doctype, page title, meta, and importing jQuery, 68-106 is the actual html, the only parts of which affected are the 2 divs, one for the select box, one for the content, the select box, and some text, everything else is fluff page design stuff, 15-67 is javascript, most of which is functions that aren't currently being used, I removed all calls. I've shown you everything that is functioning on the page.

Comment: @SpencerCole, can't you narrow down your problem to a simple page that you could show? If you can't, all I really could do is to wish you good luck in finding the issue.

Comment: I literally rebuilt it line for line, and it's working. I copied it over line by line to a new file and it stopped breaking. So theres that.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the event handler of a DOM object to a function it get passed an event object as it's argument.

```
selectBox.onchange = function(event) {
    changeFn(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);
};
```